# My Update query in SQLite isn't properly updating back to the database

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm making a form in visual studio that's able to access a database, fill a datatable with the db's table, display the datatable in a datagridview, populate editable fields on screen, and then pass those values of those fields back into the database to their respective columns. My problem is happening on the last step of that, as my update function doesn't seem to be working. I've searched around, but I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong.

```
            string query = "UPDATE Actors SET fname=@fName, lname=@lName, sex=@sex, age=@age, action=@action, comic=@comic, drama=@drama, ego=@ego, music=@music, starQual=@starQual, romance=@romance, sexApp=@sexApp, workEth=@workEth, popularity=@popularity WHERE Id=@Id";
            SQLiteConnection myConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=data.db");
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, myConnection);
            myConnection.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@fname", enterfName.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@lname", enterlName.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@sex", enterSex.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@age", Convert.ToInt32(enterAge.Value)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@action", Convert.ToInt32(enterAction.Value)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@comic", Convert.ToInt32(enterComic.Value)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@drama", Convert.ToInt32(enterDrama.Value)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ego", Convert.ToInt32(enterEgo.Value)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@music", Convert.ToInt32(enterMusic.Value)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@starQual", Convert.ToInt32(enterStarQual.Value)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@romance", Convert.ToInt32(enterRomance.Value)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@sexApp", Convert.ToInt32(enterSexApp.Value)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("workEth", Convert.ToInt32(enterWorkEth.Value)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@popularity", Convert.ToInt32(enterPopularity.Value)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(indexHold.Value)));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
            //Update gridview with the changes
            updateGridView();
```

Comment: Tel us the return value of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and the path of `myConnection`; the most common reason for this problem is the path to your database isn't what you think it is.

Comment: the return value of the ExecuteNonQuery is 1, and the path of the database is in the debug folder where I'm testing the builds. I'm pretty sure the path is right 'cause I accidentally had the update function add new rows, and it reflected in the database I was looking at in DB browser

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `@` of the parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@workEth",Convert.ToInt32(enterWorkEth.Value)));
```

Comment: You're right, good eye! Unfortunately, adding that back in doesn't fix this not updating

Comment: while the return is 1, so it means that the query had runned, so the problem is in the function `updateGridView();`

Comment: Run with debug and show us the message of the error